# In java client server program, the file contents are not transferred?

Tags: java, client

Please help me out here... the file name is being sent, the contents of the file is also read by the client, but the contents could not be sent to the server and vice versa... 
Here is the server side code...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {

public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
ServerSocket s_sock = new ServerSocket(4567);
System.out.println("Server ready for connection...");
Socket c_sock = s_sock.accept(); 
System.out.println("Connection established ...server listening...");

    // reading the filename from client

InputStream is1 = c_sock.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is1));
String f_name1 = br1.readLine();
System.out.println("File sent from client is :" + f_name1);

    // receiving file contents from client and copying

String contents1 = null;
InputStream is2 = c_sock.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br2 =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is2));
FileWriter fw1 =  new FileWriter("from_Client.txt");
BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(fw1);

        while((contents1= br2.readLine()) != null) {
            bw1.write(contents1);
        }   
System.out.println("File copied successfully");


    // reading the filename from client and sending contents to client

InputStream is3 = c_sock.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is3));
String f_name2 = br3.readLine();
System.out.println("File required by client is :" + f_name2);

String contents2 = null;
    FileReader fr2 = new FileReader(f_name2);
    BufferedReader br4 =  new BufferedReader(fr2);
OutputStream os1 = c_sock.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(os1, true);

while((contents2 = br4.readLine()) != null) {
            pw1.println(contents2);
        }   



  }

 }
```

and here is the client side code

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
Socket c_sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4567);

    //specify file name to send to server   

System.out.print("Enter the file name to upload to the server:"+"\t");
BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String f_name1 = br1.readLine();
OutputStream os1 = c_sock.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(os1, true);
pw1.println(f_name1);

    //sending file contents to server

String contents1 = null;
    FileReader fr1 = new FileReader(f_name1);
    BufferedReader br2 =  new BufferedReader(fr1);
OutputStream os2 = c_sock.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw2 = new PrintWriter(os2, true);

while((contents1 = br2.readLine()) != null) {

    pw2.println(contents1);

      } 

    //specify file name to send to server   

System.out.println();
System.out.print("Now enter the file name to download from server:"+"\t");
BufferedReader br3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String f_name2 = br3.readLine();

OutputStream os3 = c_sock.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw3 = new PrintWriter(os3, true);
pw3.println(f_name2); 

    // receiving file contents from server and copying

String contents2 = null;
InputStream is1 = c_sock.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br4 =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is1));

FileWriter fw1 =  new FileWriter("from_Server.txt");
BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(fw1);

        while((contents2 = br4.readLine()) != null) {
            bw1.write(contents2);
        }   
System.out.println("File copied successfully");



}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the second BufferedReader and use the first for everything. They are stealing data from each other.

Same applies at the client, and also to the two PrintWriters.

Of course the entire approach will only work for text files. If you send binary files through this code, they will be corrupted by the char conversions.